# Factorial manipulation with proving P(n,k)

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

I need to prove that P(n,k)=$k*P(n-1,k-1)+P(n-1,k)$
So far I have:
$$RHS=k*\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-n)!} + \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-k)!}$$
$$=k*\frac{(-1+n)!}{(n-k)!}+\frac{(n-1)!(n-k)!}{(n-1-k)!(n-k)!}$$
$$=k*\frac{(-n+1)!+(n-1)!(n-k)}{(n-k)!},$$

and then I don't know what to do.

Comment: The first expression should be $k\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}  + \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!}$

Comment: Well that would help. Now stuck with
=k*$\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}+\frac{(n-1)!(n-k)!}{(n-k)!}$

Comment: In your last line you dropped a sign on the first term in the numerator, which should be $(n-1)!$.  Fundamentally you are going the wrong way.  You are assuming what you hope to prove and hoping to get to a clear equality.  This is fine as long as every step is reversible, which is often true in combinatoric exercises because there aren't squares in the way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you have to work with.  A combinatoric proof is that $P(n,k)$ is the number of $k$ length sequences from a universe of $n$.  Pick $k$ of the universe.  Each sequence either starts with one of the $k$ or it does not.  The first term of the sum accounts for the ones that do, the second term accounts for those that do not.